# Firebase and Javascript Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a new user into the database but I don't want to have repeated user. Hence, I tried to validate and make sure that if the email stated in the form is the same as the email in the database but it kept adding in a new data although the email is already found in the database.

```
function checkUser(){
    var sFName = document.getElementById("sfname").value;
    var sLName = document.getElementById("slname").value;
    var sPassword = document.getElementById("spassword").value;
    var sEmail = document.getElementById("semail").value;
    var config = {
        apiKey: "some-key",
        authDomain: "some-domain.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://some-domain.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "some-domain.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "some-id"
    };
    if(firebase.apps.length===0){
        firebase.initializeApp(config);                         
        var database = firebase.database();
        var dbRef = database.ref('ShowOffYourTalents');
        var postData = {
            firstname : sFName,
            lastname : sLName,
            email : sEmail,
            password : sPassword,
            birthdate: "",
            gender: "",
            address: "",
            interests: "",
            NRIC: ""
        };
        dbRef.once('value',function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                var cEmail = childData.email;
                if(sEmail == cEmail){
                    document.getElementById("semail").style.borderColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("error_3").innerHTML = "User already exists!<br/>";
                }else if (sEmail !== cEmail){
                    dbRef.child(sFName+' '+sLName).set(postData);
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 
                    "Registered";
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

When the code executes, it gives out the "User already exists" but it still creates a new data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code iterates over *all* of the children under `ShowOffYourTalents`.

Presumably, each child corresponds to a user. Your `if` statement tests *each* user's email, so both the `"User already exists!"` branch *and* the `"Registered"` can be executed during the iteration.

Instead, you could use a query to look for an existing user:

```
database.ref('ShowOffYourTalents')
    .orderByChild('email')
    .equalTo(sEmail)
    .once(function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.numChildren() === 0) {
            console.log('User does not exist.');
        } else {
            console.log('User exists.');
        }
    });
```